# pexpect expect(pexpect.EOF) throws exception and not output

Tags: python, pexpect

I am using Python 2.7 and pexpect 4.6.0

As per `pexpect` [docs](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/overview.html#exceptions):

> If you wish to read up to the end of the child’s output without
>   generating an `EOF` exception then use the `expect(pexpect.EOF)` method.

But when I try that, it raises `EOF` exception. How can I expect EOF and get all output returned by the child?

```
child = pexpect.spawn("ssh user@server")
child.expect("[pP]assword")
child.sendline("password")
child.expect("\$")
print child.before + child.after
child.sendline("ifconfig")
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)    # this throws Exception
```

The docs also say this:

> Some UNIX platforms will throw an exception when you try to read from
>   a file descriptor in the EOF state. Other UNIX platforms instead
>   quietly return an empty string to indicate that the EOF state has been
>   reached.

How can we know if this is the issue? And what could be a workaround for it?

Comment: Isn't the exception a TIMEOUT exception? Because the last line would not normally see an EOF unless the server closes the connection. However, the default timeout for expect() is 30 seconds.

Comment: @meuh yes it does throw a TIMEOUT exception, but that's precisely the problem - it should not throw an exception, rather, it should match everything right? Or do you mean that EOF will be thrown ONLY when the connection is closed and NOT after each `child.send` ?

Comment: You have spawned an ssh connection to a remote host. This connection will never return eof until you send the remote shell an `exit` command, or do something similar. If you want to get the output of `ifconfig` you need to do another expect for `"\$"`, not eof. Then if you want to you can close the connection by `child.close()`.